# VBA Scipting FileSystemObject returning different time

Tags: ms-access, vba, filesystemobject

I have an issue where I'm returning the DateCreated of a file Like this:

```
Set fsoFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set File = fsoFile.GetFile([Path] & [Filename])
debug.print File.DateCreated
```

and the time it's returning is an hour earlier than it says on windows explorer?

I don't know if the System time has ever been changed, or if there was ever a period of time where the system time was wrong, but it's definitely correct now.

Anyone know what this could be/had a similar issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that you are located in Europe?

The official documentation [FILETIME structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724284(VS.85).aspx) states, that *NTFS* stores file dates as *UTC* time, thus (at present) one hour off your local time.

You can find the current UTC time this way:

```
    Public Type SystemTime
        wYear                           As Integer
        wMonth                          As Integer
        wDayOfWeek                      As Integer
        wDay                            As Integer
        wHour                           As Integer
        wMinute                         As Integer
        wSecond                         As Integer
        wMilliseconds                   As Integer
    End Type

' Returns the current UTC time.
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub GetSystemTime Lib "kernel32" ( _
    ByRef lpSystemTime As SystemTime)

' Retrieves the current date and time from the local computer as UTC.
' By cutting off the milliseconds, the resolution is one second to mimic Now().
'
' 2016-06-09. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function UtcNow() As Date

    Dim SysTime     As SystemTime
    Dim Datetime    As Date

    ' Retrieve current UTC date/time.
    GetSystemTime SysTime

    Datetime = _
        DateSerial(SysTime.wYear, SysTime.wMonth, SysTime.wDay) + _
        TimeSerial(SysTime.wHour, SysTime.wMinute, SysTime.wSecond)

    UtcNow = Datetime

End Function
```

Then use DateDiff("n", UtcNow, Now) to find the difference between UTC time and local time, and then add this to the retrieved filetime.

Comment: I am in Europe, and there does seem to be something in this. All the files I try with from before the clocks were put back, come out with the hour's difference. All the files I try since the clocks were put back, come out correct.  The DateDiff("n", UtcNow, Now) currently comes out at 0, so adding 0 to the retrieved filename won't make any difference

Comment: I guess that would be correct for the ones created now (if there's no difference between local time and UTC time, you wouldn't want/need to add anything), but adding zero won't correct the time for the files created before the clocks went back, if you see what I mean.

Comment: Yes, I see it. I'm in `UTC+01:00`. I ran a test on some local files and found, that the retrieved filedate is the _local standard time_. This means, that the time matches the displayed time outside our DST, and is one hour off within the DST (I guess, can't test under DST at this moment). Also, I found that the `VBA.FileDateTime(filename)` returns the `FSO.DateLastModified` value. For example for zip files, `DateCreated` will nearly always be different from `DateLastModified`.

Comment: Yes I had a go with DatelastModified to see if it would be any different. It isn't, same behaviour.

Comment: Some more info here: [FileTimeToLocalFileTime function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/FileAPI/nf-fileapi-filetimetolocalfiletime).

Comment: Looks complicated, I don't really understand any of that I have to say

Comment: Agree. Unfortunately, I'm busy with real work at the moment, so I can't dig further into it right now. Good question, though - I've never noticed this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll mark your answer as answer because it definitely seems to be to do with the difference between UTC time and System time etc. like you say. Noticed it because I was doing a test for a time interval tolerance between when a file is created and another event.

Comment: OK. When I find some time, I'll get back to this.